# Custom Post Type archive as front page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I basically have the same problem like in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page/30854#30854), but the *correct* answer doesn't work for me. Yes, I get a list of posts from my CPT, but the `archive-{post-type}.php` is not used to render the page. It still uses the `index.php`. Any help would be great!

This is my code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_front_page');
function my_front_page($wp_query) {
  $post_type = 'foobar';

  if ( $wp_query->get('page_id') == get_option('page_on_front') ) {
    $wp_query->set('post_type', $post_type);
    $wp_query->set('page_id', '');

    // Fix conditional functions like is_front_page or is_single
    $wp_query->is_page = 0;
    $wp_query->is_singular = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try using a `home.php` file and place your desired loop/query within that file or alternatively use `get_template_part` to retrieve a file that contains your loop.

Can you please show us your code?

What I frequently do is structure my `index.php` like so,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php if ( is_home() ) {

            get_template_part('home.php');

        } else {

           //run standard/default loop here

        } 
    ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then within `home.php` you can do literally whatever you like,

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_type' => 'custom_post_type' );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
 //get your title, content, tags, etc
endwhile;
```

With this approach **you are NOT required to set a static front page** within your dashboard settings under the normal `Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays` section.

Note: This is not the only way to achieve what you want, but a reliable method without having to resort to using any filters, if you're not comfortable with using them or in the event you're having trouble (of course saying this without seeing your code so far).

Comment: I updated my question with the code snippet I'm using

Answer (score 0):

I would try this: save your archive-{custom-post-type}. php as template-{custom-post-type}.php then post a comment like the below into the file before you call your header - change  the Template Name from "CPT" to whatever you  want.

Now create a new page and use this template file to display the content. Then go to your settings -> reading page and set Front page displays: as you new page

```
/**
 * Template Name: CPT Archive
 * 
 */
```