# CPT archive as home page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I am very new to WP coding. I am working for a University where each faculty has been allocated a CPT. We would like it so that the CPT archive looks the same as the main site. I have created the archive-post-type.php file but am at a total loss from there. From what I have seen in other questions is that the homepage is key?

I have this

```
<?php

        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content-fbe', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
        // Previous/next page navigation.
        twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

    else :
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
?>
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check this [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-name your CPT archive to home.php

Then use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the home page query so only CPT's display

```
function wpsites_home_page_cpt_filter($query) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ) {
$query->set('post_type', array( 'your-cpt' ) );
    }
  }

add_action('pre_get_posts','wpsites_home_page_cpt_filter');
```

Replace `your-cpt` with the name of your custom post type.

**Note:** `pre_get_posts` won't work with the `is_front_page()` conditional tag.

Comment: Does && is_home() mean the homepage of the site? What's happening now is the CPT is displaying the archive in the homepage. Is that right? As I am trying to create 4 homepage like styles for each custom post type archive page.

Comment: My question subject should be more Homepage as CPT archive, if that helps...

Comment: Tested and works. Rename archive-cpt.php to home.php where cpt is the name of your custom post type