# Prevent <title> change with new query_posts()

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I have to display 12 items of my custom post type on the front page of my theme. However, when I do this, the page title (`<title>...</title>`) changes to `Custom Post Type archive - Page Title`.

Since this is the front page, I just want this to have the normal frontpage title, namely `Page title - page tag line`. Is there any way to set this variable in the new `query_posts()`? Or to just prevent that the page title changes, when using a new `query_posts()`?

I don't mind this happening on sub-pages and such, but on the front page, it shouldn't change when I filter resutls on `post_type`.

This is the query I use right now:

```
query_posts( array( 
   'post_type' => 'bwps',
   'posts_per_page' => 12
));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a custom post type archive as front page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `query_posts()` at all. From [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/):

> Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t
>   intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach
>   to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided
>   wherever possible. In most cases, there are better, more performant
>   options for modifying the main query such as via the ‘pre_get_posts’
>   action within WP_Query.

If you want to show some custom posts on your front page, then you should create a template for the front page (either [front-page.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) or a [custom template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). Then, on that template, query for those posts with your own `WP_Query`:

```
$bwps = new WP_Query( array( 
   'post_type' => 'bwps',
   'posts_per_page' => 12
) );
```

And loop through them with the query methods on `$bwps`:

```
if ( $bwps->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $bwps->have_posts() ) : $bwps->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

If you want to keep *Your home page displays* set to *Your latest posts*, and to keep pagination on the home page, just replacing those latest posts with your own post type, then see [this previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page) on the topic.