# Homepage rewrite rule

Tags: rewrite-rules, frontpage

I'm trying to display a product tag archive page (WooCommerce) as my basic-main-root domain (mydomain.com).

It can be done with the 'shop' page (via WordPress front-page settings) - which is the same as product tag archive page in principle (as I understand at least). But I can't seem to find a way to mimic it for a product tag archive page.

WordPress is somehow chopping the "/shop/" part from the URL, while still showing the page content.

I spent hours trying to understand the logic/mechanism for this - but I couldn't.

What am I missing?

This is not a duplicate of 'How to use a custom post type archive as front page?'.

The result might be the same, but I want to take a different approach. I've tried to change the query and it worked in the beginning, but broke after WooCommerce update. I don't think it is a good solution. Especially when WooCommerce is soon to separate products from the native WordPress post tables.

I'm asking here about a different approach to get the result - a more future-proof one. As I understand - I can somehow use rewrite rules to make the archive page seem as the main domain - as happens when you set the 'shop' page as the front-page via WordPress settings.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a custom post type archive as front page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page)

Comment: As I explained in an edit, it is not a duplicate. How can I dismiss the duplication notice?

Comment: You can't. But what you can is to explain what exactly you understand as a future-proof approach and why exactly you consider the answers to the duplicate not being future-proof. Thanks

Comment: OK, it seems like a safer why to do so is to set 'shop' as homepage and to use the `woocommerce_product_query` to change the query to the desired one. I hope i'm correct.