# Make a page return false to is_single() and true for is_post_type_archive() before wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: wp-query

I am using a page to replace custom post type archive.  I used page template in that page to query CPTs like a CPT archive

The problem is, since I conditionally load different css files based on the page, I want this page to return `false` to `is_single()` and `true` to `is_archive()` so that it won't break my conditional.  How can I achieve this?  What is the earliest hook I can use?

Comment: This is a terrible approach. Why is your archive a page template anyway? If it is a page, then why are you using the archive conditional. If it's a page, check for the page.

Comment: I want to make CPT archive a page as I want to use it as the site front page, also for the ease of management on meta title and description.

Because the content it loads should belongs to an archive, therefore it needs to pass conditional for is_archive() and get those CSS

Comment: assuming the page needs to use a custom page template for the code, why do you not check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ and adjust your conditional check for what CSS to load?

Comment: It will be really tedious, as I not only need to add this conditional tags for every is_archive() used, I also need to set conditional to negate every is_single() in every plugin.

Comment: What you want to do is a hack, and is more likely to introduce issues than resolve them. You want to use a page to be able to use meta descriptions etc, but setting the page to appear as `is_archive()` will probably stop that form working anyway. It might be tedious but it seems like you have some much larger architectural issues that need to be resolved.

Comment: I see.  Is there a better way to pull this off?  I just want to use CPT archive as the front page of my website, while keeping the blog page for 'post'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a custom post type archive as front page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page)